# Print output of c++ .exe file in java

Tags: java, c++

I want to run c++ .exe file from java and also want to print the output of .exe file.i tried and succeed to run c++ .exe file from java ,but i am not getting how can i print the output(in java output field) of c++ .exe file using java,i tried using processExitValue and waitfor  methods but not getting desired output.The java code is here

```
int processExitVal = 0;
         try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c  start rs.exe");
        processExitVal = p.waitFor();
       // p.getOutputStream();
        //InputStreamReader ir=new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
       //BufferedReader t = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())));
       // int y=Integer.parseInt(t.readLine());
        InputStream in=p.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(in.read());
        //System.out.println("output"+Process.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("InterruptedException");
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       System.out.println(processExitVal);
       System.out.println("Execution complete");
}
```

I will be thankful if u will help me out this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: A start is to replace `getInputStream` with `getOutputStream`.

Comment: `getInputStream` should be fine

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: @AndrewThompson they talk about the exit value of the process ,but i want to print the output of the c++ .exe file in java output field .Do i need to change the c++ code or return some value from main method ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Scanner` and then read lines from it. Are you sure your process is writing something on the standard output?

Edit:

> read(): Reads the next byte of data from the input stream.

You have to use a Scanner:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
String line = scan.getNextLine();
```

Regarding Deestan's answer: `getInputStream()` is the correct method here, we want the output of the process, that's an input for the application.

Comment: same case with scanner also,it wont work.please tell me if i need to do some changes in c++ to return some value from main method.process is executing fine ,i don't know about standard output of the process

Answer (score 0):

Use "rs.exe" instead of "cmd /c  start rs.exe"

As example:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rs.exe");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: cmd /c  start rs.exe is fine ,rs.exe wont work ,BufferedReader i have already used ,if u can see the comments in my code ,suggest something else please :)